# Share C++ struct between two files

Tags: c++, struct, share

I would like to share a C++ struct between two files (in context of Android-NDK programming). In the first one the struct is initialized and in the other one it is finally used.

So I define the struct in a header file struct.h (which I include in both .cpp files) and declare it as a static variable:

```
struct A {
   int v;
   A(){
    v = 0;
   }
}

static A structA;
```

Then I assign a value to it in the first i.cpp-File e.g.: A.v = 5. But when I call it in the second one j.cpp it`s still 0.

The whole process looks like this:

Java Code -> call i.cpp and assign value -> Java Code -> call j.cpp and read value -> wrong

but

Java Code -> call i.cpp and assign value -> Java Code -> call i.cpp and read value -> correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, what you want to share is an **object**, not a struct. The struct defines the **type** of the object.

Second, `static` means "don't share this with other translation units". I'll bet you stuck that in there because without it you got a complaint from the linker about duplicate definitions.

The way to do that is to **declare** the object in the header and **define** it in only one place. This goes in the header:

```
extern A structA;
```

And this goes in the source file where you want to initialize it:

```
A structA;
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because of the `static` keyword when you declare the variable `structA`. This makes the variable unique in each source file the header file is included in.

If you declare the variable `extern` instead of `static`, and define it in one source file (without `static` or `extern`)  you should see that it works.